# Using webworker and IndexedDB for loader of Three js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, three.js, indexeddb, web-worker

I want to use dracoLoader of threeJS in multi-threads, then I selected Webworker and IndexedDB. I have gotten the correct Geometry in webworker, however, when I pass data to main thread using IndexedDB, the geometry will be changed to a normal JS object instead of a ThreeJS Geometry. The geometry lost its functions and some information.

webworker.js

```
self.saveDrcToIndexedDB = function (drcfinal) {

  var db;
  var request = indexedDB.open("drcDB");

  drcfinal.indexName = self.randomStr();

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {

    console.log('successfully upgraded db');  

    db = event.target.result;
    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("drcfinal", { keyPath: "indexName"});
  };

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {

    console.log('successfully opened db');

    db = event.target.result;
    var transaction = db.transaction(["drcfinal"], "readwrite");

    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("drcfinal");
    objectStore.add(drcfinal).onsuccess = function(event) {
      self.postMessage(drcfinal.indexName);
    };
  } 
}
```

main.js

```
var worker = new Worker('webworker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

  indexedDB.open("drcDB").onsuccess = function(event) {

    let db = event.target.result;   
    let objectStore = db.transaction(["drcfinal"]).objectStore("drcfinal");

    objectStore.get(e.data).onsuccess = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.result);
    };
  }

}, false);

worker.postMessage(somedata);
```

Can I transfer a correct geometry to main thread? Or using other tools instead of IndexedDB? Or using other multi-threading tools instead of webworker?

Answer (score 5):

A mechanism called [Structured Cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) is used when storing data in IndexedDB. Same applies to sending messages to and from WebWorkers via `postMessage`. It is not possible with this approach to duplicate functions. Thus you cannot transfer complete objects including their methods. Simply put, it is a better `JSON.stringify/parse` approach since Structured Cloning can e.g. handle cyclic dependencies.

AFAIK all web-browser available multi threading mechanisms such as WebWorker, SharedWorker and ServiceWorker use this actor based message sending approach.

However, you could use a [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) object to transfer data from a WebWorker to the main thread using [Worker.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage). This way, you could send `THREE.Geometry`'s vertex array as a `Transferable`. E.g. when using a `THREE.BufferGeometry` within WebWorker.

```
const myVertexData = bufferGeometry.getAttribute('position').array.buffer;
self.postMessage({myVertices: myVertexData}, [myVertexData]);
```

This is quite fast since the data is not copied but only its ownership is changed.

Comment: Hi @tomacco, is it enough to transfer the arrayBuffer of the vertices in order to create a new BufferGeometry back in the main thread?

Comment: I answer myself: yes it is if one is handling **colors** and **indices** separately. On the main thread, one's ought to code: `const vertexBuffer = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(myVertexData, 3); let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(); geometry.addAttribute('position', vertexBuffer);` Hope it helps!